# Атака на сайт через htaccess возможна?

Tags: .htaccess, php

Как может быть организована атака на сайт через файлики htaccess?

Как защитится от такого рода атак...?

Просто интересно стало если залью на сайт  файлик это ведь может быть атакой(припустим через форму....)?

Может кто-то скажет про другие виды атак через htaccess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможна даже на самом примитивном уровне, если админ, мягко говоря, дурак. Если позволить кому угодно заливать файлы без их предварительной проверки в корень приложения(или даже в его далекую папку, что в общем-то не так уж важно), то такой сайт может быть взломан без особых усилий. В крайнем случай, deface`нут( т.е испорен ) конфигурационным файлом. 
Чтобы обезопасить себя, достаточно просто понимать, что пользователям незачем загружать в папку файлы с расширением .htaccess через форму предназначенную для загрузки изображений.

Чтобы понять, сколько появится у злоумышленника возможностей с залитием на сервер своего .htaccess файла, достаточно пробежать глазами по документации .htaccess, предоставленной Apache.

Comment: спасибо...А если СURL отправлять файлы на сервер он ведь тоже будет использоватся?Нужно все временные файлы хранить далеко за пределами директории сайта?

Comment: По поводу cURL не совсем понял вопрос( в связи с отсутствием знаков препинания ). А вот по поводу того, где лучше хранить файлы, существует много споров. Я, как и большинство, думаю, что по возможности выгоднее хранить ссылки на файлы, а не сами файлы. А уже по ссылкам загружать содержимое файлов. Если же это невозможно, то лучше хранить файлы на отдельном хосте, который занимается только отдачей статики(файлов).

Comment: Я говорю про временную директорию сервера загрузки файлов....
Наверно лучше поменять стандартный адрес загрузки.
А по поводу СURL  я имел ввиду следующее - мы ведь через CURL тоже можем отправить файл ,даже если нету формы загрузки....

Comment: Временные файлы, само собой, нужно хранить в tmp директории, находящейся недалеко от корня. cURL-запросы ничем не отличаются от запросов, посылаемых формой( как правило, GET && POST ), cURL-это своего рода эмулятор(имитатор, если так нравится) пользователя в браузере. Он, в свою очередь, является расширением( эволюцией ) Linux-утилиты wget. Так что, неважно, от кого идут запросы - от имитатора или от реального человека, важно лишь то, как они обрабатываются на стороне сервера.

P.S Принять вы можете любой файл, но что с ним делать дальше - вопрос, зависящий от задачи.